# Group by unique occurrences and sum all individual occurrences present in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a MySQL query for following:

```
product  Occur
---------------
alpha      3
beta       5
gamma      2 
beta       1
gamma      6
alpha      0
```

and what I want:

```
Product  total(Occur)
-------------------
alpha      3
beta       6
gamma      8
```

Comment: SELECT product, SUM(occur) AS total FROM product_table GROUP BY product

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(occur)  FROM tableName GROUP BY product
```

you need to enter table name. so you will chose "occur" values from occur column from YOUR TABLE, group them by "product" and sum those products in the same group.

SELECT SUM(occur) AS total  FROM tableName GROUP BY product

this will sort the result under "total" column. you can name anything you want.